# Android application open and close in the same time. Why?

Tags: android, syntax-error

My application do not have erro in th code, however the aplication open and close. Is it something related with id, layout ?

```
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


// Função principal do programa que extende fragmentos 
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {  
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout; 
    private ListView mDrawerList; 
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle; // CharSequence como o nome indica é uma sequencia de char, ou seja, texto 
    private CharSequence mTitle; // CharSequence como o nome indica é uma sequencia de char, ou seja, texto 
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private ImageView mIcon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // responsável por exibir a tela da minha aplicação , baseado nos layouts xml.
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle(); // Gets the title of the frame (String) 
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array); // Pela minha lista de string com o nome dos planetas
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); // Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        // ira colocar no list view localizado do drawer_layout, um layout do tipo drawer_list_item, usando os nomes dos planetas
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_icon, mPlanetTitles));
        //Registrar um callback para ser chamado quando um produto neste AdapterView foi clicado .
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }




    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
         // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            // create intent to perform web search for this planet
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
            // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

         Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
         Bundle args = new Bundle();
         FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        switch(position){   
        case 0:
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case 1:
             // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
            //QuestionActivity articleFrag = (QuestionActivity)
             //       getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FrameLayout1);
            Fragment newfragment = new QuestionActivity();
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            args.putInt(QuestionActivity.ARG_POSITION, position);
            newfragment.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, newfragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            //FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getFragmentManager();
            //Fragment frag1 =(Fragment) fragmentManager1.findFragmentById(R.id.);
            //Bundle args1 = new Bundle();

            //Fragment frag1 =(Fragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.)
             // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
           // Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
          //  startActivity(i);
            // close this activity
           Toast.makeText(this, "Indicativo de acao ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break; 

        case 2:
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break; 

        case 3:
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break; 

        case 4:
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case 5:
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case 6:
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case 7:
             // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
            Intent j = new Intent(this, ScreenSplash.class);
            startActivity(j);
            // close this activity
            finish();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Indicativo de acao ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;          
            }        
    }




    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }




    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }



    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
     */
    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                            "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
            ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
            getActivity().setTitle(planet);
            return rootView;
        }
    }


}
```

**drawer_list_icon (xml)** I think that the erro is here, but i do not know where.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#F3F3F3" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- 
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
     -->
```

**logcat**

```
11-14 18:38:49.200: D/OpenGLRenderer(4973): Enabling debug mode 0
11-14 18:38:49.210: E/ArrayAdapter(4973): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
11-14 18:38:49.210: D/AndroidRuntime(4973): Shutting down VM
11-14 18:38:49.210: W/dalvikvm(4973): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x64c97b20)
11-14 18:38:49.210: D/BstCommandProcessor-Application(3198): Application crash has been observed. 
11-14 18:38:49.210: W/BstCommandProcessor-Application(3198): in sendHttpRequest, requestType is of CRASH_APP type but one of the requiredInfo is NULL, crashedApp = com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor.BstCrashedAppInfo@327a2da8
11-14 18:38:49.210: D/BstCommandProcessor-Application(3198): in sendHttpRequest, request to send to (fqdn): http://10.0.2.2:2861/AppCrashedInfo
11-14 18:38:49.210: D/BstCommandProcessor-Application(3198): data: {"packageName":"com.exemplo.myapp","shortPackageName":"com.exemplo.myapp","versionCode":1,"versionName":"1.0"}
11-14 18:38:49.210: D/AndroidRuntime(4973): procName from cmdline: com.exemplo.myapp
11-14 18:38:49.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4973): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.exemplo.myapp
11-14 18:38:49.210: D/AndroidRuntime(4973): file written successfully with content: com.exemplo.myapp StringBuffer : ;com.exemplo.myapp
11-14 18:38:49.220: I/Process(4973): Sending signal. PID: 4973 SIG: 9
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973): Process: com.exemplo.myapp, PID: 4973
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14876)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:714)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14876)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14876)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14876)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14876)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1994)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1751)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1007)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5677)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
11-14 18:38:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     ... 40 more
11-14 18:38:49.230: I/ActivityManager(3006): Process com.exemplo.myapp (pid 4973) has died.
```

Comment: could you post the logcat?

Comment: Or better the stacktrace of the logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ArrayAdapter` constructor you're using assumes a layout consisting of only a single `TextView`. To use your layout which also includes a `RelativeLayout`, you need to use the [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T[]%29) which allows you to specify the `TextView` that the adapter will use.

Instead of

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.drawer_list_icon, mPlanetTitles));
```

use

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.drawer_list_icon, android.R.id.text1, mPlanetTitles));
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. So it is necessary to write android before R.id. I will learn more about this. :)

Comment: `android.R.id` refers to platform-defined ids, which show up in xml as `@android:id/...` Quite often, you will define your own ids using `@+id/...` in xml, and these ids you can get in java from your package's `R.id`.